# How to not use nested try catch blocks when parsing JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, try-catch

Is there a more elegant solution to my code below than to have multiple nested try-catch blocks for `JSONException`?

The reason I nest them is because I don't want to rest of the parsing to stop if there is one error in parsing. I want each to be independent of each other.

```
if (obj.has(GlobalVars.KEY_DESC)) {
        try {
            JSONObject descObj = obj.getJSONObject(GlobalVars.KEY_DESC);

            if (descObj.has(GlobalVars.KEY_COUNTRY)) {
                try {
                    description.put(GlobalVars.KEY_COUNTRY, descObj.getString(GlobalVars.KEY_COUNTRY));
                }
                catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }

            if (descObj.has(GlobalVars.KEY_CITY)) {
                try {
                    description.put(GlobalVars.KEY_COUNTRY, descObj.getString(GlobalVars.KEY_CITY));
                }
                catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }

            if (descObj.has(GlobalVars.KEY_POSTAL)) {
                try {
                    description.put(GlobalVars.KEY_COUNTRY, descObj.getString(GlobalVars.KEY_POSTAL));
                }
                catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }

            if (descObj.has(GlobalVars.KEY_STREET)) {
                try {
                    description.put(GlobalVars.KEY_COUNTRY, descObj.getString(GlobalVars.KEY_STREET));
                }
                catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }

            if (descObj.has(GlobalVars.KEY_SUBSTREET)) {
                try {
                    description.put(GlobalVars.KEY_COUNTRY, descObj.getString(GlobalVars.KEY_SUBSTREET));
                }
                catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }

            if (descObj.has(GlobalVars.KEY_YEAR)) {
                try {
                    description.put(GlobalVars.KEY_COUNTRY, descObj.getInt(GlobalVars.KEY_YEAR));
                }
                catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }

            if (descObj.has(GlobalVars.KEY_SQUARE_METERS)) {
                try {
                    description.put(GlobalVars.KEY_COUNTRY, descObj.getInt(GlobalVars.KEY_SQUARE_METERS));
                }
                catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't care about exception, make a single method and parameter appropriately with return type. Parameter to method would be KEY you are using for lookup in above code.

Comment: you want to check every field if there continue otherwise stop parsing?

Comment: @Nambari I do care about the exception. I would like to see what went wrong in the logs.

Comment: @SafwanHijazi I want each key parsing to be independent of each other. So if it is missing one key, I want it to continue.

Comment: You can simply log and still my suggestions stands.

Comment: @Nambari Yes I have implemented separate methods for `getStringFromObject` and `getIntFromObject`. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @TheNomad, try to use Gson lib, it continue parsing if field missing, please check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to use all these try catch if you use `Gson` lib, it ignored missing fields and continue the parsing, but you can register the missing fields by using the below code:

```
package json;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(
                MyAnnotationBean.class,
                new AnnotatedDeserializer<MyAnnotationBean>()).create();

        String json = "{\"desc\":\"This is desc\",\"country\":\"this is country\"}";
        MyAnnotationBean tab = gson.fromJson(json, MyAnnotationBean.class);
        System.out.println(tab.desc);
        System.out.println(tab.country);

        json = "{\"desc\":\"This is desc\"}";
        tab = gson.fromJson(json, MyAnnotationBean.class);
        System.out.println(tab.desc);
        System.out.println(tab.country);

        json = "{\"country\":\"This is country\"}";
        tab = gson.fromJson(json, MyAnnotationBean.class);
        System.out.println(tab.desc);
        System.out.println(tab.country);
    }
}


class MyAnnotationBean {
    public String desc;
    public String country;
}

class AnnotatedDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

    public T deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type,
            JsonDeserializationContext jdc) throws JsonParseException {
        T obj = new Gson().fromJson(je, type);

        Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : fields) {
                try {
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    if (f.get(obj) == null) {
//                       throw new JsonParseException("required json " +
//                       f.getName());

                        // add your code to know missing fields
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        return obj;

    }
}
```

Comment: This was probably the easiest solution and quick too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You seems to be doing similar stuff in all of your `if` statements:

```
            try {
                description.put(GlobalVars.KEY_COUNTRY, descObj.getString(GlobalVars.KEY_COUNTRY));
            }
            catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

So you can move this code to a method and can call that method from each if statement. It will make your code cleaner